# How to convert this.state with index for React Hooks API

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks, react-state-management

I'm converting a react component from class to function. I was able to change most of the code, however I got stuck at one point. Specifically this function where `this.state` has an *index*:

```
const sortRows = (rows,property,sortBy) => {
        if (this.state[sortBy] === 'asc'){
            rows.sort(function(a,b){
                if (a[property] !== null && b[property] !== null){
                return a[property].localeCompare(b[property]);}
            })
        }
        if (this.state[sortBy] === 'desc'){
            rows.sort(function(a,b){
                if (a[property] !== null && b[property] !== null){
                return b[property].localeCompare(a[property]);}
            })
        }
        return rows
    }
```

The above function is called like this:

```
rows = sortRows(rows, "field_firstname", "sortFirstName");
```

Where `sortFirstName` is another state variable.

How can `this.state[sortBy]` be converted for a function approach?

Comment: From a quick scan, I think you need to refactor this so that `sortBy` becomes an array of sorted columns i.e. `let [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState([]);` & `const sortRows = (rows, property, sortByIndex) => { if (sortBy[sortByIndex] === 'asc'){ //... } }`. You could set the state as such, `setSortByIndex = (index, direction) => setSortBy([...sortBy, index: direction ])` (where `direction` is either `'asc'` or `'desc'`)

Comment: I've tried the first part.. It doesn't trigger any error but it doesn't sort the columns. How should I use the second part of the code (`setSortByIndex`)?

Comment: How are the sortBy column indices currently being set? Also, when is `sortRows` called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [diogo.silva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64769599/how-to-convert-this-state-with-index-for-react-hooks-api/64771043#64771043) answer and [nbokmans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64769599/how-to-convert-this-state-with-index-for-react-hooks-api?noredirect=1#comment114518543_64769599) comment I was able to find a solution. Here is how I modify the function accordingly.

```
const sortRows = (rows, property, sortedBy) => {
        if (sortBy[sortedBy] === 'asc' || sortBy[sortedBy] === ''){
            sortBy[sortedBy] = 'desc';
            rows.sort(function(a,b){
                if (a[property] !== null && b[property] !== null){
                return a[property].localeCompare(b[property]);}
            });
        } else if (sortBy[sortedBy] === 'desc'){
            sortBy[sortedBy] = 'asc';
            rows.sort(function(a,b){
                if (a[property] !== null && b[property] !== null){
                return b[property].localeCompare(a[property]);}
            });
        }
        return rows
    }
```

Where `sortBy` state is defined as follows:

```
let [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState({
        "sortFirstName": "",
        "sortLastName": "",
        "sortStatus": ""
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your sorting callbacks are doing what you want them to do and that they work as you have posted them, you should first define `sortBy` as a state variable:

```js
const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState('asc'); // set here your default
```

And then have your `sortRows` function use that state variable's value.

```js
const sortRows = (rows, property) => {
  if (sortBy === 'asc'){
    rows.sort(function(a, b){
      if (a[property] !== null && b[property] !== null) {
        return a[property].localeCompare(b[property]);
      }
    });
  } else if (sortBy === 'desc'){
    rows.sort(function(a, b){
      if (a[property] !== null && b[property] !== null) {
        return b[property].localeCompare(a[property]);
      }
    });
  }
  return rows;
};
```

You can then update the value of the `sortBy` state variable using the setter:

```js
setSortBy('asc');

setSortBy('desc');
```

---

In case your `sortBy` is actually meant to be used in sorting multiple different entities, the following applies:

```js
const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState({}); // set default as empty
```

```js
const sortRows = (rows, property, sortedBy) => {
  if (!sortBy[sortedBy] || sortBy[sortedBy] === 'asc') { // this is the default
    rows.sort(function(a, b){
      if (a[property] !== null && b[property] !== null) {
        return a[property].localeCompare(b[property]);
      }
    });
  } else if (sortBy[sortedBy] === 'desc'){
    rows.sort(function(a, b){
      if (a[property] !== null && b[property] !== null) {
        return b[property].localeCompare(a[property]);
      }
    });
  }
  return rows;
};
```

And you can change those properties' sorting by setting it in `sortBy`:

```js
const updateSorting = (sortedBy, direction) => {
  setSortBy(sortBy => {
    return { ...sortBy, [sortedBy]: direction };
  });
};

updateSorting('posts', 'desc');
```

Comment: Where will `sortRows` be called?

Comment: When you need to get the rows for then rendering / using.

Comment: I've tried to call `updateSorting` inside the `sortRows` function, but it trigger `Too many re-renders` error. However if I put `sortBy[sortedBy] = 'asc';` the sorting works.

Comment: I posted an answer. I don't know if calling `sortBy[sortedBy] = 'asc';` is the best approach to change of a object state